# Calculate the cube root of a number

Tags: code-golf, math

The goal of this code golf is to create a program or function that calculates and outputs the cube root of a number that's given as input.
The rules:

- No external resources
- No use of built-in cube root functions.
- No use of methods/operators that can raise a number to a power (that includes square root, 4th root, etc.).
- Your function/program must be able to accept floating-point numbers and negative numbers as input.
- If the cube root is a floating-point number, then round it to 4 numbers after the decimal point.
- This is a code golf, the shortest code in bytes wins.

Test cases:

```
27 --> 3
64 --> 4
1  --> 1
18.609625 --> 2.65
3652264 --> 154
0.001 --> 0.1
7  --> 1.9129
```

You can use all test cases above to test negative numbers (`-27 --> -3`, `-64 --> -4` ...)

Comment: damn, if you allowed only numbers with precise cube, I would have a nice golf

Comment: Judging from your test cases I assume the program only needs to deal with real numbers?

Comment: @ace add complex and I change 2 letters in my code ;)

Comment: Is rounding to 4 digits after the decimal point a strong requirement? Or could it be something like "you aren't required to show more than 4 digits after the decimal point"?

Comment: With reference to my answer using Exp(ln(x)/3) (and several clones of it) please clarify if Exp is allowed. I assume pow(x,1/3) is not (even though it is technically not a cube root function.)

Comment: @ace: Yes, only real numbers.

Comment: Is a built-in for square-root allowed? By this, I mean that the builtin for square root is a single byte command and not a builtin that raises a number to the .5 power

Comment: @KritixiLithos No, it isn't. I understand that this wasn't really clear, but my intent was to disallow them. And I'm not invalidating any answers with this, so I updated the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## J: 16 characters

Loose translation of the Haskell answer:

```
-:@((%*~)+])^:_~
```

Test cases:

```
   -:@((%*~)+])^:_~27
3
   -:@((%*~)+])^:_~64
4
   -:@((%*~)+])^:_~1
1
   -:@((%*~)+])^:_~18.609625
2.65
   -:@((%*~)+])^:_~3652264
154
   -:@((%*~)+])^:_~0.001
0.1
   -:@((%*~)+])^:_~7
1.91293
```

It works like this:

```
     (-:@((% *~) + ])^:_)~ 27
↔ 27 (-:@((% *~) + ])^:_) 27
↔ 27 (-:@((% *~) + ])^:_) 27 (-:@((% *~) + ])) 27
↔ 27 (-:@((% *~) + ])^:_) -: ((27 % 27 * 27) + 27)
↔ 27 (-:@((% *~) + ])^:_) 13.5185
↔ 27 (-:@((% *~) + ])^:_) 27 (-:@((% *~) + ])) 13.5185
↔ 27 (-:@((% *~) + ])^:_) -: ((27 % 13.5185 * 13.5185) + 13.5185)
↔ 27 (-:@((% *~) + ])^:_) 6.83313
...
```

In words:

```
half =. -:
of =. @
divideBy =. %
times =. *
add =. +
right =. ]
iterate =. ^:
infinite =. _
fixpoint =. iterate infinite
by_self =. ~

-:@((%*~)+])^:_~ ↔ half of ((divideBy times by_self) add right) fixpoint by_self
```

Not one of the best wordy translations, since there's a dyadic fork and a `~` right at the end.

Answer (score 19):

## Haskell - 35

```
c n=(iterate(\x->(x+n/x/x)/2)n)!!99
```

Example runs:

```
c 27  =>  3.0
c 64  =>  4.0
c 1  =>  1.0
c 18.609625  =>  2.6500000000000004  # only first 4 digits are important, right?
c 3652264  =>  154.0
c 0.001  =>  0.1
c 7  =>  1.9129311827723892
c (-27)  =>  -3.0
c (-64)  =>  -4.0
```

Moreover, if you import `Data.Complex`, it even works on complex numbers, it returns one of the roots of the number (there are 3):

```
c (18:+26)  =>  3.0 :+ 1.0
```

The `:+` operator should be read as 'plus *i* times'

Comment: This deserves a +1. I've been refactoring generalized nth root algs for the last hour, and I just now arrived at the same result. Bravo.

Comment: @primo I instantly recalled all n'th root approximation algorithms, and after giving up on Taylor/Maclaurin series in APL I used this.

Comment: Using Newton method I got `x=(2*x+n/x/x)/3`, can you explain why you can use `x=(x+n/x/x)/2` ? It converges slower but I can't explain why it converges...

Comment: @Michael because if you take `x=cbrt(n)`, then `x=(x+n/x/x)/2` is true. So is it true for your expression

Comment: @Michael I got there this way: http://codepad.org/gwMWniZB

Comment: @mniip Instantly recalled [all of them](http://codepad.org/nR32U7g2)? That's just a handful; there are, of course, infinitely many.

Comment: @primo those are formulas, algorithms are more generic

Comment: @mniip Hmm, I suppose you're right, those were all generated with the same method, really. My primary concern at the time was convergence rate.

Answer (score 8):

### SageMath, (69) 62 bytes

However, don't ever believe it will give you the result, it's very difficult to go randomly through all the numbers:

```
def r(x):
 y=0
 while y*y*y-x:y=RR.random_element()
 return "%.4f"%y
```

if you didn't insist on truncating:

```
def r(x):
 y=0
 while y*y*y-x:y=RR.random_element()
 return y
```

### SageMath, 12 bytes, if `exp` is allowed

Works for all stuff: positive, negative, zero, complex, ...

```
exp(ln(x)/3)
```

Comment: I believe you are using an operator that can raise a number to a power.

Comment: ah ok, right, edited

Comment: +1 for a monumentally stupid algorithm that still satisfies the requirements.

Comment: @Mechanicalsnail Thanks. I hope it's obvious that what I do is a sort of recession :D However, if `exp` is allowed, I'm down to 12 and not being stupid at all :)

Comment: Considering that `exp` is short for "exponential function", which is "a function whose value is a constant raised to the power of the argument, especially the function where the constant is e.", and there is "No use of methods/operators that can raise a number to a power", `exp` is not allowed.

Comment: @mbo well, the problem statement is not quite clear regarding this; it explicitly mentions only power functions as examples of what's forbidden, but no exponentials.

Comment: An **exponent**ial *is* a power function. I quoted the definition right there. It raises a number to a power.

Answer (score 5):

### Python - 62 bytes

```
x=v=input()
exec"x*=(2.*v+x*x*x)/(v+2*x*x*x or 1);"*99;print x
```

Evaluates to full floating point precision. The method used is [Halley's method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halley%27s_method). As each iteration produces 3 times as many correct digits as the last, *99* iterations is a bit of overkill.

Input/output:

```
27 -> 3.0
64 -> 4.0
1 -> 1.0
18.609625 -> 2.65
3652264 -> 154.0
0.001 -> 0.1
7 -> 1.91293118277
0 -> 1.57772181044e-30
-2 -> -1.25992104989
```

Comment: How does this work?

Comment: @justhalf I think this is the Newton's method of approximation basically.

Comment: Btw, fails on `0`

Comment: Fails on `-2`, sorry for that.

Comment: @tohecz fixed for all cases.

Comment: You can save space using powers (`x*x*x == x**3`), also this allows you to save a space on the `or` (it follows a number and Python knows the number can't be the beginning of an identifier). `exec"x*=(2.*v+x**3)/(v+2*x**3or 1);"*99;print x` :)

Comment: @plg The problem description forbids the use of any exponential function, otherwise `v**(1/.3)` would be a sure winner.

Comment: Oh right, oops! :p

Answer (score 3):

### Javascript (55)

`function f(n){for(i=x=99;i--;)x=(2*x+n/x/x)/3;return x}`

**BONUS, General formulation for all roots**
`function f(n,p){for(i=x=99;i--;)x=x-(x-n/Math.pow(x,p-1))/p;return x}`

For cube root, just use `f(n,3)`, square root `f(n,2)`, etc...
Example : `f(1024,10)` returns `2`.

**Explanation**
Based on Newton method :

Find : `f(x) = x^3 - n = 0`, the solution is `n = x^3`
The derivation : `f'(x) = 3*x^2`

Iterate :
`x(i+1) = x(i) - f(x(i))/f'(x(i)) = x(i) + (2/3)*x + (1/3)*n/x^2`

**Tests**

```
[27,64,1,18.609625,3652264,0.001,7].forEach(function(n){console.log(n + ' (' + -n + ') => ' + f(n) + ' ('+ f(-n) +')')})

27 (-27) => 3 (-3)
64 (-64) => 4 (-4)
1 (-1) => 1 (-1)
18.609625 (-18.609625) => 2.65 (-2.65)
3652264 (-3652264) => 154 (-154)
0.001 (-0.001) => 0.09999999999999999 (-0.09999999999999999)
7 (-7) => 1.912931182772389 (-1.912931182772389)
```

Comment: One character shorter: `function f(n){for(i=x=99;i--;)x-=(x-n/x/x)/3;return x}`

Comment: Can be reduced to 47 bytes `f=(n)=>eval('for(i=x=99;i--;)x=(2*x+n/x/x)/3')`

Answer (score 3):

### Perl, 92 bytes

```perl
sub a{$x=1;while($d=($x-$_[0]/$x/$x)/3,abs$d>1e-9){$x-=$d}$_=sprintf'%.4f',$x;s/\.?0*$//;$_}
```

- The function `a` returns a string with the number without
  an unnecessary fraction part or insignificant zeroes at the right end.

Result:

```
              27 --> 3
             -27 --> -3
              64 --> 4
             -64 --> -4
               1 --> 1
              -1 --> -1
       18.609625 --> 2.65
      -18.609625 --> -2.65
         3652264 --> 154
        -3652264 --> -154
           0.001 --> 0.1
          -0.001 --> -0.1
               7 --> 1.9129
              -7 --> -1.9129
 0.0000000000002 --> 0.0001
-0.0000000000002 --> -0.0001
               0 --> 0
              -0 --> 0
```

Generated by

```
sub test{
    my $a = shift;
    printf "%16s --> %s\n", $a, a($a);
    printf "%16s --> %s\n", "-$a", a(-$a);
}
test 27;
test 64;
test 1;
test 18.609625;
test 3652264;
test 0.001;
test 7;
test "0.0000000000002";
test 0;
```

The calculation is based on [Newton's method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method):

[image: Calculation]

Answer (score 2):

### PHP - 81 bytes

Iterative solution:

```
$i=0;while(($y=abs($x=$argv[1]))-$i*$i*$i>1e-4)$i+=1e-5;@print $y/$x*round($i,4);
```

Comment: What happens if it tries to calculate the cube root of zero?

Comment: It will just output "0" (thanks to the error suppression operator - "@").

Comment: `0.0001` can be replaced by `1e-4` and `0.00001` by `1e.5`.

Comment: This requires PHP<7 (`0/0` gives `NAN` in PHP 7). `$i=0;` is unnecessary (-5 bytes. If it wasn´t, `for` would save one byte.) The space after `print` is not required (-1 byte). `-R` can save 3 bytes with `$argn`.

Comment: Save a pair of parantheses with `while(1e-4+$i*$i*$i<$y=abs($x=$argn))` (-2 bytes).

Answer (score 2):

### Javascript: 73/72 characters

This algorithm is lame, and exploits the fact that this question is limited to 4 digits after the decimal point. It is a modified version of the algorithm that I suggested in the sandbox for the purpose of reworking the question. It counts from zero to the infinite while `h*h*h<a`, just with a multiplication and division trick to handle the 4 decimal digits pecision.

```javascript
function g(a){if(a<0)return-g(-a);for(h=0;h*h*h<1e12*a;h++);return h/1e4}
```

Edit, 4 years later: As suggested by Luis felipe De jesus Munoz, by using `**` the code is shorter, but that feature was not available back in 2014 when I wrote this answer. Anyway, by using it, we shave an extra character:

```javascript
function g(a){if(a<0)return-g(-a);for(h=0;h**3<1e12*a;h++);return h/1e4}
```

Comment: Instead `h*h*h` you can do `h**3` and save 1 byte

Comment: @LuisfelipeDejesusMunoz This answer is from 2014. The `**` operator was proposed in 2015 and was accepted as part of ECMAScript 7 in 2016. So, at the time that I wrote that, there was no `**` in the language.

Answer (score 2):

### Java, <strike>207</strike> <strike>182</strike> 181

Sometimes when I play golf I have two many beers and play really really bad

```java
class n{public static void main(String[]a){double d=Double.valueOf(a[0]);double i=d;for(int j=0;j<99;j++)i=(d/(i*i)+(2.0*i))/3.0;System.out.println((double)Math.round(i*1e4)/1e4);}}
```

Iterative Newton's Method of Approximation, runs 99 iterations.

Here is the unGolfed:

```java
class n{
    public static void main(String a[]){
        //assuming the input value is the first parameter of the input
        //arguments as a String, get the Double value of it
        double d=Double.valueOf(a[0]);
        //Newton's method needs a guess at a starting point for the 
        //iterative approximation, there are much better ways at 
        //going about this, but this is by far the simplest. Given
        //the nature of the problem, it should suffice fine with 99 iterations
        double i=d;

        //make successive better approximations, do it 99 times
        for(int j=0;j<99;j++){
            i=( (d/(i*i)) + (2.0*i) ) / 3.0;
        }
        //print out the answer to standard out
        //also need to round off the double to meet the requirements
        //of the problem.  Short and sweet method of rounding:
        System.out.println( (double)Math.round(i*10000.0) / 10000.0 );
    }
}
```

Comment: You may rename the `args` variable to something like `z`, reducing 6 chars. You may remove the space and the curly braces in the body of the for-loop, reducing 3 chars. You may replace `10000.0` by `1e4`, reducing 6 chars. The class does not needs to be public, so you can reduce more 7 chars. This way it will be reduced to 185 characters.

Comment: Is the cast at the end really necessary? It does not for me.

Comment: @Victor Thanks for the good eye, the use of E notation for the 10000.0 double was a spectacularly good idea.  By the design of the question, I think it is legit to make this a method instead of a functioning cli class, which would reduce the size considerably.  With Java, I didn't think I had a chance, so I erred on the side of functional.

Comment: Welcome to CodeGolf! Don't forget to add an in-answer explanation of how this works!

Comment: @Quincunx, Thanks, made recommended change.

Comment: you can drop the `(double)` and `.0`s

Comment: You can save a few more chars: flip the location of the `[]` in the main method, and use `Double` instead of `double` for d, change `#.0` to `#`, use `System.out.print`: `class n{public static void main(String[]a){Double d=0;d=d.valueOf(a[0]);double i=d;for(int j=0;j<99;j++)i=(d/(i*i)+(2*i))/3;System.out.print((double)Math.round(i*1e4)/1e4);}}` Also, consider using `Float`s instead of `Doubles`.

Comment: Except I need to debug it....

Comment: @Quincunx: Thanks, lot of good ideas here.  I think it would need to be Double d=0.0;d=d.valueOf which is longer than double d=Double.valueOf.  I didn't know that the space could be ommitted from the array decleration in String[]a, awesome tip!

Comment: @md_rasler The standard for declaring arrays is with the array on they type, not on the variable. Also, don't forget that you can leave off the `0` after the `0.`

Answer (score 2):

## TI-Basic, <s>26</s> 24 bytes

```
Input :1:For(I,1,9:2Ans/3+X/(3AnsAns:End
```

Comment: That directly uses the `^` operator, doesn't it. It is forbidden by the rules

Comment: @mniip: Is `e^` is a single operator on the TI-83 series? I don't remember. Either way, it's violating the spirit of the rules.

Comment: @Mechanicalsnail It doesn't matter I would say. In most languages you could just do `exp(ln(x)/3)` or `e^(ln(x/3))` if you allowed any of these two. But somehow I understand to `exp(ln(x)/a)` as too much equivalent to `x^(1/a)` to be allowed by the rules :-/

Comment: Exponential function: "a function whose value is a constant **raised to the power of the argument**, especially the function where the constant is e." ... "No use of methods/operators that can raise a number to a power"

Comment: Thanks for the catch @mbomb007, I wrote this answer more than 3 years ago and I will fix it to comply now.

Answer (score 2):

## APL - 31

```
(×X)×+/1,(×\99⍴(⍟|X←⎕)÷3)÷×\⍳99
```

Uses the fact that `cbrt(x)=e^(ln(x)/3)`, but instead of doing naive `⋆` exponentiation, it computes `e^x` using Taylor/Maclaurin series.

Sample runs:

```
⎕: 27
3
⎕: 64
4
⎕: 1
1
⎕: 18.609625
2.65
⎕: 3652264
154
⎕: 0.001
0.1
⎕: 7
1.912931183
⎕: ¯27
¯3
⎕: ¯7
¯1.912931183
```

Seeing as there's a [J answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/21871/7162) in 16 characters, I must be really terrible at APL...

Answer (score 2):

### Js 57 bytes

`f=(x)=>eval('for(w=0;w**3<1e12*x;w++);x<0?-f(-x):w/1e4')`

```js
f=(x)=>eval('for(w=0;w**3<1e12*x;w++);x<0?-f(-x):w/1e4')
document.getElementById('div').innerHTML += f(-27) + '<br>'
document.getElementById('div').innerHTML += f(-64) + '<br>'
document.getElementById('div').innerHTML += f(-1) + '<br>'
document.getElementById('div').innerHTML += f(-18.609625) + '<br>'
document.getElementById('div').innerHTML += f(-3652264) + '<br>'
document.getElementById('div').innerHTML += f(-0.001) + '<br>'
document.getElementById('div').innerHTML += f(-7) + '<br><hr>'
document.getElementById('div').innerHTML += f(27) + '<br>'
document.getElementById('div').innerHTML += f(64) + '<br>'
document.getElementById('div').innerHTML += f(1) + '<br>'
document.getElementById('div').innerHTML += f(18.609625) + '<br>'
document.getElementById('div').innerHTML += f(3652264) + '<br>'
document.getElementById('div').innerHTML += f(0.001) + '<br>'
document.getElementById('div').innerHTML += f(7) + '<br>'
```

```html
<div id="div"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

### Javascript - 157 characters

This function:

- Handle negative numbers.
- Handle floating-pointing numbers.
- Execute quickly for any input number.
- Has the maximum precision allowed for javascript floating-point numbers.

```javascript
function f(a){if(p=q=a<=1)return a<0?-f(-a):a==0|a==1?a:1/f(1/a);for(v=u=1;v*v*v<a;v*=2);while(u!=p|v!=q){p=u;q=v;k=(u+v)/2;if(k*k*k>a)v=k;else u=k}return u}
```

Ungolfed explained version:

```javascript
function f(a) {
  if (p = q = a <= 1) return a < 0 ? -f(-a)      // if a < 0, it is the negative of the positive cube root.
                           : a == 0 | a == 1 ? a // if a is 0 or 1, its cube root is too.
                           : 1 / f (1 / a);      // if a < 1 (and a > 0) invert the number and return the inverse of the result.

  // Now, we only need to handle positive numbers > 1.

  // Start u and v with 1, and double v until it becomes a power of 2 greater than the given number.
  for (v = u = 1; v * v * v < a; v *= 2);

  // Bisects the u-v interval iteratively while u or v are changing, which means that we still did not reached the precision limit.
  // Use p and q to keep track of the last values of u and v so we are able to detect the change.
  while (u != p | v != q) {
    p = u;
    q = v;
    k = (u + v) / 2;
    if (k * k * k > a)
      v=k;
    else
      u=k
  }

  // At this point u <= cbrt(a) and v >= cbrt(a) and they are the closest that is possible to the true result that is possible using javascript-floating point precision.
  // If u == v then we have an exact cube root.
  // Return u because if u != v, u < cbrt(a), i.e. it is rounded towards zero.
  return u
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## PHP, 61

Based on Newton's method. Slightly modified version of [Michael's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/21774/13847):

```
for($i=$x=1;$i++<99;)$x=(2*$x+$n/$x/$x)/3;echo round($x,14);
```

It works with negative numbers, can handle floating point numbers, and rounds the result to 4 numbers after the decimal point if the result is a floating point number.

[**Working demo**](https://eval.in/104560)

Comment: You can save two bytes with `for($x=1;++$i<100;)...`. But using predefined variables as input is [generally frowned upon](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/8731#8731). Better use `$argv[1]` or `$argn`.

Answer (score 1):

## GameMaker Language, 51 bytes

```
for(i=x=1;i++<99;1)x=(2*x+argument0/x/x)/3;return x
```

Answer (score 1):

## Smalltalk, 37

credit goes to mniip for the algorithm; Smalltalk version of his code:

input in n; output in x:

```
1to:(x:=99)do:[:i|x:=2*x+(n/x/x)/3.0]
```

or, as a block

```
[:n|1to:(x:=99)do:[:i|x:=2*x+(n/x/x)/3.0].x]
```

Answer (score 1):

## Befunge 98 - Work in progress

This language does not support floating point numbers; this attempts to emulate them. It currently works for positive numbers that do not start with `0` after the decimal point (mostly). However, it only outputs to 2 decimal places.

```
&5ka5k*&+00pv
:::**00g`!jv>1+
/.'.,aa*%.@>1-:aa*
```

It works by inputting the part before the decimal point, multiplying that by `100000`, then inputting the part after the point and adding the two numbers together. The second line does a counter until the cube is greater than the inputted number. Then the third line extracts the decimal number from the integer.

If anyone can tell me why the third line only divides by `100` to get the correct values, please tell me.

IOs:

```
27.0       3 .0
64.0       4 .0
1.0        1 .0
18.609625  2 .65
0.001      0 .1
7.0        1 .91

0.1        0 .1
```

Answer (score 0):

### Haskell: 99C

Can't beat @mniip in cleverness. I just went with a binary search.

```
c x=d 0 x x
d l h x
 |abs(x-c)<=t=m
 |c < x=d m h x
 |True=d l m x
 where m=(l+h)/2;c=m*m*m;t=1e-4
```

Ungolfed:

```
-- just calls the helper function below
cubeRoot x = cubeRoot' 0 x x

cubeRoot' lo hi x
    | abs(x-c) <= tol = mid           -- if our guess is within the tolerance, accept it
    | c < x = cubeRoot' mid hi x      -- shot too low, narrow our search space to upper end
    | otherwise = cubeRoot' lo mid x  -- shot too high, narrow search space to lower end
    where
        mid = (lo+hi)/2
        cubed = mid*mid*mid
        tol = 0.0001
```

Comment: You can use an infix operator for `d` (like `(l#h)x`) to save a byte for each call. `c` then becomes `id>>=(0#)`.

Comment: You can remove spaces around `c < x`.

Comment: You can use `1>0` instead of `True`.

Answer (score 0):

### J 28

```
*@[*(3%~+:@]+(%*~@]))^:_&|&1
```

Using Newtons method, finding the root of `x^3 - X` the update step is `x - (x^3 - C)/(3*x^2)`, where x is the current guess, and C the input. Doing the maths on this one yields the ridiculously simple expression of `(2*x+C/x^2) /3` . Care has to be taken for negative numbers.

Implemented in J, from right to left:

1. `|` Take abs of both arguments, pass them on
2. `^:_` Do until convergence
3. `(%*~@])` is `C / x^2` (`*~ y` is equivalent to `y * y`)
4. `+:@]` is `2 x`
5. `3%~` divide by three. This yields the positive root
6. `*@[ * positive_root` multiplies positive root with the signum of C.

Test run:

```
   NB. give it a name:
   c=: *@[*(3%~+:@]+(%*~@]))^:_&|&1
   c 27 64 1 18.609625 3652264 0.001 7
3 4 1 2.65 154 0.1 1.91293
```

Answer (score 0):

### AWK, 53 bytes

```
{for(n=x=$1;y-x;){y=x;x=(2*x+n/x/x)/3}printf"%.4g",y}
```

Example usage:

```
$ awk '{for(n=x=$1;y-x;){y=x;x=(2*x+n/x/x)/3}printf"%.4g",y}' <<< 18.609625 
2.65$
```

Thanks go to @Mig for the `JavaScript` solution which this is derived from. It runs surprisingly quickly given that the `for` loop requires the iteration to stop changing.

Answer (score 0):

## C, 69 bytes

```
i;float g(float x){for(float y=x;++i%999;x=x*2/3+y/3/x/x);return x;}
```

Just another implementation of Newton's method. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/c-gcc#NY/dqsIwEITv@xSDIjT2J3iKFyXWJ/Emx3Y1kCbSphiRvrqxOXpg2WGH@WB2rcxZT213GF2rbHk9Jut/p5fuuhhBCdJWOlzSj3r2JDt8j0fjRZapTV3Xwjd@@8Or7MEr7rlnYujcNBh4MQdlHHqpTMqeCRB5tHb61R2oKfYCdIgra8odGGIEuA0LRClWG8LfnMwqB@W42Xu6yK7kFctjLQYmFmRO5vA6k5aXMRREcnRF/CEUun8D)

Answer (score 0):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 10 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)<sup>CP437</sup>

```
╘♀┘A╕äO¶∩'
```

[Run and debug online!](https://staxlang.xyz/#c=%E2%95%98%E2%99%80%E2%94%98A%E2%95%95%C3%A4O%C2%B6%E2%88%A9%27&i=27%0A64%0A1%0A18.609625%0A3652264%0A0.001%0A7&a=1&m=2)

### Explanation

Uses the unpacked version to explain.

```
gpJux*_+h4je
gp              Iterate until a fixed point is found, output the fix point
  Ju            Inverse of square
    x*          Multiplied by input
      _+h       Average of the value computed by last command and the value at current iteration
         4je    Round to 4 decimal digits
```

Answer (score 0):

**JAVA Solution**

public BigDecimal cubeRoot(BigDecimal number) {

```
    if(number == null || number.intValue() == 0) return BigDecimal.ZERO;
    BigDecimal absNum = number.abs();
    BigDecimal t;
    BigDecimal root =  absNum.divide(BigDecimal.valueOf(3), MathContext.DECIMAL128);


    do {

        t = root;
        root = root.multiply(BigDecimal.valueOf(2))
                .add(absNum.divide(root.multiply(root), MathContext.DECIMAL128))
                .divide(BigDecimal.valueOf(3), MathContext.DECIMAL128);

    } while (t.toBigInteger().subtract(root.toBigInteger()).intValue() != 0);

    return root.multiply(number.divide(absNum), MathContext.DECIMAL128);
}
```

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! This is a [tag:code-golf] challenge, which means the goal is to solve the challenge is as little code as possible (counted in bytes of the source file). You should show some effort towards optimising your solution towards that goal and include the byte count in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

**Python Solution**

```
def cube_root(num):
    if num == 0:
        return 0

    t = 0
    absNum = abs(num)
    root = absNum/3

    while (t - root) != 0:
        t = root
        root = (1/3) * ((2 * root) + absNum/(root * root))

    return root * (num / absNum)
```

Answer (score 0):

## MMIX, 44 bytes (11 instrs)

```
E0013FF0 48000002 E8018000 C1FF0100
1001FFFF 14010001 040101FF E401FFF0
11FF01FF 53FFFFFA F8020000
```

## Disassembly

```
cbrt    SETH  $1,#3FF0      // y = 1.
        BNN   $0,0F         // if(x >= 0) goto loop (ensuring sign is correct)
        ORH   $1,#8000      // y = fnabs(y) (bit tricks!)
0H      SET   $255,$1       // loop: prev = y
        FMUL  $1,$255,$255  // y = prev *. prev
        FDIV  $1,$0,$1      // y = x /. y
        FADD  $1,$1,$255    // y = y +. prev
        INCH  $1,#FFF0      // y = y /. 2. (bit tricks again)
        FCMPE $255,$1,$255  // prev = comp_eps(y, prev)
        PBNZ  $255,0B       // if(prev) goto loop
        POP   2,0           // return {y,x}
```

It is up to the caller to set a suitable value of `rE`. Much faster convergence may be arranged by essentially setting `y` up by dividing the exponent by 3, but that costs another four instructions (though in time it pays really quickly, since three `FDIV`s cost about the same amount as two `DIV`s):

```
cbrt    SLU  $1,$0,1    // 3B010001 shift left to erase sign
        INCH $1,#8020   // E4018020 unbias exponent
        DIV  $1,$1,3    // 1D010103 divide by 3 as integer; approximate cube root
        INCH $1,#7FE0   // E4017FE8 rebias exponent
        SRU  $1,$1,1    // 3F010101 shift right again
```

and then continue from the second line in the original.

If mispredicted branches are particularly expensive, I would also replace the second and third lines of the original with:

```
        ZSN $255,$0,1       // 71020001 $255 = ($0 neg? 1 : 0)
        SLU $255,$255,63    // 3B02023F $255 <<= 63
        OR  $1,$1,$255      // C0010102 $1 |= $255
```

This costs one more instruction, but is branchless.